# Is there anything faster than Veency for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, remote-desktop

I want to be able to [control an iPhone](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/01/12/tuaw-tip-veency-remote-controls-your-iphone-from-your-mac/) with a PC or Mac—that is, see the iPhone's screen on a computer and control it with my mouse—via either USB or wireless. Are there any solutions faster than [VNC Veency](http://cydia.saurik.com/info/veency/)? Veency's frame rate isn't good enough, and I need it to show 16-bit color.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried Veency on both an iPhone 3G and an iPhone 4, and that looks to be the fastest possible speed to get out of it. Unless someone rewrites Veency or writes another VNC server, it looks doubtful that speed would get any better.

I've relegated myself to either looking at the iPhone's screen while typing, or pairing a Bluetooth keyboard with the iPhone.

**Edit:** If you don't mind looking at the iPhone's screen, you could try [iSynergyClient](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/isynergyclient.php), the [Synergy+](http://synergy-foss.org/) client for iPhone. Right now it only has mouse support, keyboard support is still in development.

Comment: +1 for mentioning iSynergyClient. Hadn't come across that one, and am eager to try it out. Too bad it doesn't have keyboard support yet; that would be _so_ cool.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new Cydia app, called Display Recorder. Beside screen recording, it has a local web client, with the abilily to stream live view almost flawlessly.

You can buy it from the BigBoss repo for $4,99.

You stream by opening the Display Recorder app itself, enable web server with the bottom left button, type the url that shows up in a browser on the PC, and select Live View option (while being on the same wifi of cource).

It will even add touch and hardware button simulation right away, but sadly no keyboard support, so you'll need to open a VNC client too in the background, possibly set its refresh rate to never, and here you go. Most probably you can even set your video card to rotate the screen to align with the iPhone screen if you prefer landscape.

Comment: +1 for Display Recorder. I had looked at it previously, but it didn't have live view at the time. Looks compelling. Too bad it doesn't do keyboard, though. Surely there would be keyboard focus issues with the VNC app in the background, but it could work, I suppose, to some degree.